# Restore backups to postgres instance on another server through pgbackrest

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pgbackrest

I'm trying to backup/restore from one postgres instance on one virtual machine to another postgres on another vm. How to give paths in pg_hba.conf?

```
[global]
repo1-path=/var/lib/pgsql/12/backups/
log-level-console=info
log-level-file=debug
start-fast=y
repo1-retention-full-type=time
repo1-retention-full=15

[my_stanza]
pg1-path=/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/
```

Also is it possible to restore on another postgres instance if backups are stored on S3, GCS or Azure? If yes, How?